# "C" wire in wall! Where does it go in air handler/furnace?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Got a wifi thermostat. Behind the old thermostat was a blue "C" wire. The other side of the blue wire in the equipment room isn't plugged into anything. I need to get the 24v common hooked up to this blue but don't know where it goes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: diagram]

[image: wires]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiring diagram you posted is quite clear on what it wants you to do; namely, it wants the C wire connected to the furnace chassis ground.  To do that, simply drill/tap a 10-32 hole in a suitable spot on the furnace chassis if there isn't one present already, screw a premade ground pigtail into it, and nut the C wire to that pigtail.

Comment: I could simply unscrew the Chassis Ground (there is a screw that already has a blue wire from the condensing unit going to it) and put this blue wire there and screw back in.  I don't think I would need to drill a new hole.  I'm not following how this would provide constant power to a smart wifi thermostat..... if I am hooking it up to a ground, how it is getting power?

Comment: @user3330299 -- the thermostat already has the 24VAC side in the form of the R wire, you just need to close the circuit with a C wire to provide a return path for that juice besides through the furnace board :)

Comment: While technically this will work, it's not exactly the correct way to do it.  By connecting the `C` wire to the chassis, you're effectively using the chassis as a current carrying conductor.  I guess it's only possibly ~1A @ 24V, but still.   It's like telling somebody to connect the neutral to the ground on a receptacle, and you wouldn't do that, would you?

Comment: @user3330299 If you know anything about AC wiring, you can think of the `R` wire as the ungrounded (hot) conductor, and the `C` as the grounded (neutral) conductor.  In the furnace, `C` (neutral) is bonded to ground (the frame). So connecting the neutral from the thermostat to ground, gives it a path back to the source (albeit and inappropriate path, in my opinion).

Comment: If the furnace Chassis is an inappropriate ground, then how or where would I ground this out?  String the wire outside of the furnace and onto something else in the utility room?  Also, I do want to mention that the "optional condensing unit" which there is one, has the two wires hooked up as the diagram shows with the blue from that into a screw into the furnace chassis.  I agree with your stance though but at the same time could it be wrong or dangerous if the electrical diagram shows to do that specifically for the air handler blue wire?

Comment: @Tester101 -- the reason I used the chassis as the C wire return is because the wiring diagram says to connect the C wire returning from the condensing unit contactor to the chassis, not directly to the transformer.

Comment: @user3330299 the chassis is ground, that's not the problem.   Connecting a current carrying conductor (`C`) to the chassis, to use the chassis as a current carrying conductor is.  To do it properly,  the `C` wire should be connected together with all the other "C" wires.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that's likely because the manufacturer doesn't want installers messing around with the factory installed wiring.  It's an accepted practice in the HVAC industry, but in my opinion it's a bad practice.  Telling the OP to connect the thermostat `C` to the same chassis screw as the condensing units `C` (using properly sized ring terminals), would have been a bit of a better answer.  Telling the OP to willy-nilly  ground the wire to the chassis, is not so great (while technically acceptable). I mean what are we, the auto industry?

Comment: @Tester101My air condensing unit has the yellow and blue hooked up to the yellow from the t-stat and the blue goes into a WIRE NUT and then the other wire in the wire nut goes under a screw in the furnace chassis as per the electrical diagram.  Can't I simply put the t-stat "C" blue wire in the WIRE NUT with the air condensing blue wire and the wire that goes to the furnace chassis so that there are three wires in this wire nut?  Wouldn't that have the same result?

Comment: @user3330299 -- yes, that'd work as well.

Answer (score 2):

- If there's a C terminal on your board (can't tell from picture), use that.
- If you have an air conditioner, it will have two wires that connect back to the thermostat (usually via the furnace): so long as one is going to `R`, the other will be `C` and you can splice into the same spot.
- Lastly, you can splice into a wire from the transformer. You'll need a multi-meter to figure out which one it is (measure 24V between the `C` side of the transformer and the `R` terminal).

  - It does look like common is grounded to the chassis, so you can also use that to identify the side of the transformer -- find the side that has a wire connected to the chassis.

  It'll be one of the bottom two terminals:

  [image]

#### Test

You should use the multi-meter to test -- no matter which method you use -- before you actually splice into anything.

With the furnace powered on but not actually running (fan off, heat off), you should measure `24V AC` between the `R` and the place you're hooking into.